# Stack multiple columns

Tags: text-processing

I would like to change a file so that column N+1 would be put at the end of column N for each N = odd number.
For instance, if I had a file with 4 columns, the column 2 would be pasted at the end of column 1 and the column 4 at the end of column 3.

Example file:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Output file:

```
1 3
1 3
1 3
2 4
2 4
2 4
```

My files have ~100 lines and ~60000 columns.

Comment: What do you mean Gilles? That I'm a student? Well no, sorry, I am a research scientist (population genetics), working on Structure software and trying to get the number of polymorphic sites from a file. I managed to get it from a test file except this file transformation that I asked about...

Comment: The output does not correspond to the description. In the output, column N and N + 2 are kept together.

Comment: Yes, not clear.

Comment: My apologies if that is not clear. I said that I want column N+1 pasted at the end of column N and N only is an ODD number. So column 2 should be found at the end of column 1, and column 4 at the end of column 3 and so on. But column 1, 3 and all other odd number columns don't move!

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

for c in 0 1; do
  while read -r -a columns; do
    for((i=$c; i<${#columns[@]}; i+=2)); do
      echo -n "${columns[$i]} "
    done
    echo
  done < file
done
```

Output:

```
1 3 
1 3 
1 3 
2 4 
2 4 
2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some fairly cryptic awk:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {printf "%s ", $(i + (NR > FNR))}; print ""}' file file
```

The first time you process the file, `NR > FNR` will be false, or 0.
The second time you process the file, `NR > FNR` will be true, or 1.

---

This one requires a single pass through the file, but you have to keep half the file in memory:

```
awk '
    {
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
            printf "%s ", $i
            row[NR] = row[NR] $(i+1) " "
        }
        print ""
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print row[i]
    }
' file
```